# Rails 2.2.2 issue: undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on Rails 2.2.2 application. For this I installed rvm with Ruby version 1.9.3p551. There  is no Gemfile for this application. So as mentioned in the environment.rb file I created a Gemfile with rails and sqlite3. While running rake db:create, I am facing the following issue.

```
whoami@myvm:~/Desktop/practice/store$ rake db:create
/home/whoami/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/rake:22:in `<main>': undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/whoami/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/whoami/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For me, (I am working with RVM) it worked just running:

```
gem update --system
gem update bundler
```

Comment: Thank you! Just confirmed with Rails 5.0.0.1 and Ruby 2.3.1 also.

Comment: It also appears to work on Rails 2.3.18 and Ruby 1.9.3. (Hooray for legacy code. :-p)

Comment: I tried this on macOS Sierra and due to system integrity protection the last command needs to be changed to `gem install bundler -n /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 2):

This normally occurs when you have multiple versions of RVM and gem sets and its normally comes for ruby 2.2.2 the best way to get rid of this ERROR is.

First Update your system gems by using the following

```
 gem update --system   

 OR  

 update_rubygems --system
```

Then you have to update your bundler:

```
 gem update bundler
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried these commands

Rename /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/ to site_ruby.bak/
  Run the following commands:

```
gem install rubygems-update
enter code here
update_rubygems
```

If you get error then try the following instead:

ruby --disable-gems -S update_rubygems

Comment: I am using rvm and there is no site_ruby folder/file.

Comment: you need to check where your ruby installed

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, when running the standalone `passenger`, it worked fine. However, running it using a systemd service gave the same error as the OP:

```
undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I've managed to solve it using

```
env | egrep 'gem|rvm|ruby' > passenger.env
```

and adding it to the service file using `EnvironmentFile=[...]/passenger.env`.

Hopefully, this will be useful for other people stuck on this.

Comment: thanks. this solved my problem. Do you know why this is happening? My experience so far with systemd has been disappointing, and I want to go back to upstart.

Comment: It's because the environment variables weren't visible to `systemd`, but I don't know what's the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try run through the `bundle`

```
cd myapp
gem install bundler
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:create
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /lib/ruby/gems/* 

export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
```

Actually these steps worked for me.

Comment: Using syntax highlight makes your answer more clear :)