# Error installing cocoapods: Error with json-1.8.3 and more

Tags: ios, rubygems, cocoapods

I can't install `cocoapods`. I'm doing this:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

And I get all these errors:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161228-19158-1ru87yt.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
generator.c:861:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cFixnum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                        ^
generator.c:863:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cBignum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                        ^
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2143:9: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2329:8: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2201:11: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 4 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2167:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2162:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2158:12: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2143:9: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2329:8: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2201:11: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 4 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2167:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2163:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs+1, varc, vari+1))
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2158:12: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2143:9: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2329:8: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2201:11: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 4 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2168:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs+1, varc, vari+1))
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2162:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2158:12: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2143:9: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2329:8: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2201:11: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 4 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2167:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2162:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2158:12: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2143:9: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2329:8: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2201:11: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 4 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2167:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2162:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2158:12: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2143:9: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2329:8: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2201:11: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 5 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2167:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2162:6: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2158:12: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
6 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
```

I have been searching a lot and I can't find anything about those errors.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that [JSON 1.8.3 is not compatible with ruby 2.4.](http://JSON%201.8.3%20is%20not%20compatible%20with%20ruby%202.4) . I think they're fixing that right now. In meantime I solved similar issue by downgrading to ruby 2.3

Comment: In case it helps others: `brew switch ruby 2.3.3` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/1988505) and `sudo gem update --system` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39775255/1988505) I found to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I installed the Cocoapods app from their site, which allowed me to build the cocoapods I needed for my app (integrating firebase).

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6299#issuecomment-269282062

Installing the command line tools seemed to work for me, but hopefully the broken dependency (json1.8.3) will be fixed so that this builds correctly.

Hopefully this helps you until a more permanent solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with gem 'github-pages', trying to install json..

Solved my issue by downgrading to ruby 2.3 using this :

`brew install rbenv ruby-build

Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.3.3
rbenv global 2.3.3
ruby -v`

from : https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra