# nohup command working in localhost but not working in production mode rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, production-environment

Getting error when calling from production rails console

```
ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:22:in `<main>': undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help you fix the problem [undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805525/rails-2-2-2-issue-undefined-method-activate-bin-path-for-gemmodule-nomethod)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @vee, but facing same issue.