# Sass --Watch error on Linux

Tags: css, ruby, linux, sass

I'm running `sass --watch` to process my css files into scss files. I'm not sure if it's how it works, but I've navigated to the folder in my terminal, and ran the following command:

`~/Documents/Website Development/Kedanco/kedanco-website/assets$ sass --watch sass:css`

And the following is the error message:

```
Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem 
pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  
Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-9.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.1.0
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.3
Ignoring ffi-1.9.18 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.18
Ignoring json-1.8.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.6
Ignoring nio4r-2.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.1.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.0
Ignoring puma-3.10.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine puma --version 3.10.0
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.13 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.13
Ignoring therubyracer-0.12.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine therubyracer --version 0.12.3
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.6.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.6.5
/home/kelvin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/sass:22:in `<main>': undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
from /home/kelvin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/kelvin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I'm familiar with Ruby & Rails, but I'm not using it for this website, it's just a plain static site. Any idea if the target folder was off or I'm using the sass command wrongly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 2.2.2 issue: undefined method \`activate\_bin\_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805525/rails-2-2-2-issue-undefined-method-activate-bin-path-for-gemmodule-nomethod)

Answer (score 0):

`sass --watch <input folder>:<output folder>`

sass-watch watches a directory, and when scss files in the input directory are added/changed/deleted, those changes are reflected in the compiled css files in the output directory.